# How to get value from a form and process it in functions.php file of WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to submit a form that posts data and then process this data on functions.php file. 
In detail, my form is pretty simple, having a single button in the Woo-commerce logging page for the user to click if he/she wants to continue as a guest.

I have tried to follow the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672292/wordpress-form-action-functions-php-file).

This is the form I have created in form-login.php:

```
<form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() );?>">
                <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="guest" value="guest" />
                    <input class="woocommerce-Button button" type="submit" name="continue_as_guest" value="Continue as guest" />
                </p>
</form>
```

And this is the source code added in the functions.php:

```
function redirect_pre_checkout() {
    $redirect_page_id = 21;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && ($_REQUEST['continue_as_guest'] !== 'guest') ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
        die;
    } elseif($_REQUEST['continue_as_guest'] == 'guest') { 
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) );
        die;
    }
}.
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_pre_checkout' );
```

The page with id equal to 21 is the login page and Woo-commerce option for guest chechout is on. 
So, the logic is that if the user is not logged in and the user is proceeding to checkout and the user has not selected to proceed as guest, then redirect the user to the login page. Differently, if the user has selected to continue as guest, redirect him to the checkout page.

Unfortunately, this is not working as $_REQUEST['continue_as_guest'] is not getting the value (guest). Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the function should be more like this:

```
function redirect_pre_checkout() {
    $redirect_page_id = 21;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && !isset( $_POST['continue_as_guest']) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
        die;
    } elseif( isset( $_POST['continue_as_guest']) ) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) );
        die;
    }
}.
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_pre_checkout' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this didn't work, still $_POST['continue_as_guest'] is not getting a value, so the condition is not met.